# How do I get id number from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables: `qanda` and `comment`. Here is the structure of them:

```
// qanda
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
| id |   title  |       content        | related | type |
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
| 1  | a title  | a content            | NULL    | 0    |
| 2  |          | a content            | 1       | 1    |
| 3  | a title  | a content            | NULL    | 0    |
| 4  |          | a content            | 1       | 1    |
| 5  |          | a content            | 3       | 1    |
+----+----------+----------------------+---------+------+
/*  type column:     "0" means it is a question, "1" means it is a answer
    related column:  it contains the id number of its own question
*/

// comment
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+
| id | post_id | user_id |     content     |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1       | 324523  | a content       |
| 2  | 5       | 435243  | a content       |
+----+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

I have just a `id` from `comment` table. This is my current query:

```
SELECT post_id FROM comment WHERE id = :id
```

**Current output:**

```
// assuming :id = 2
+---------+
| post_id |
+---------+
| 5       |
+---------+
```

But I also need to select the id of its own question. So this is **expected result:**

```
// assuming :id = 2
+-------------+---------+
| question_id | post_id |
+-------------+---------+
| 3           | 5       |
+-------------+---------+
```

Well how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you just need to `join` the tables together:

```
SELECT c.post_id, q.related
FROM comment c
    join qanda q on c.post_id = q.id
WHERE c.id = :id
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming id in qanda table is post_id and related is the question_id, this query should get the job done:

```
SELECT qanda.related AS question_id, qanda.id AS post_id
FROM qanda, comment
WHERE comment.id = id AND qanda.id = comment.post_id
```